# Identifying one specific local variable

Tags: java, bytecode, instrumentation, java-bytecode-asm

Let's say I have a class, an instance of which must be passed to all methods, either by argument or via a getter function.

```
package asmvisit;

public class B {
    public void foo(int x, Crucial c){
        c.value = x;
    }

    public void bar(int c){
        Crucial crucial = Crucial.get();
        crucial.value = c;
    }
}
```

The reason for the getter to exist is that certain methods' arguments cannot be modified without violating java security policies (i.e. crashing).

I know that the instance of `Crucial` being worked on may change during the execution of the method but that if it does, the dedicated local variable will always hold a reference to it. Because these were inserted by instrumentation, I cannot rely on its having the same name in all methods.

I *should* be able to rely on its being the first local variable to which a `Crucial` object is assigned to.

The idea, then, is to identify it exactly like that.

If it's an argument, then I should be able to easily identify using 
[Types.getArgumentTypes](http://asm.ow2.org/asm50/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/Type.html#getArgumentTypes-java.lang.String-) -- e.g.

```
public class MyClassVisitor extends ClassVisitor {
    public MyClassVisitor(ClassVisitor cv) {
        super(Opcodes.ASM5, cv);
    }

    @Override
    public MethodVisitor visitMethod(int access, String name, String desc, String signature, String[] exceptions) {

        Type[] argtypes = Type.getArgumentTypes(desc);
        String argtypeString = Arrays.toString(argtypes);
        System.out.println(String.format("argtypes = %s",argtypeString));

        String targetType = "Lasmvisit/Crucial;";
        int index;
        if(argtypeString.contains(targetType)){
            index = ((access & Opcodes.ACC_STATIC) == 0 ? 1 : 0); //"this" is not included in {@code argtypes}

            for(Type t : argtypes){
                if(t.toString().equals(targetType)) break;
                else index += ((t.equals(Type.DOUBLE_TYPE) || t.equals(Type.LONG_TYPE)) ? 2 : 1);
            }

        }else index = -1;

        MethodVisitor mv = super.visitMethod(access, name, desc, signature, exceptions);
        if(mv != null){
            return new MyMethodVisitor(api,mv, index);
        }

        return mv;
    }
}
```

Now, if `new MyMethodVisitor(api,mv, index);` receives a nonnegative `index`, it'll just use that.

On the other hand, if it does receive a negative `index`, the idea is to override *something* that would allow detection as we traverse the code.

I could, of course, go for a two-pass version, where in the first, I use the [visitLocalVariable](http://asm.ow2.org/asm50/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/MethodVisitor.html#visitLocalVariable-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-org.objectweb.asm.Label-org.objectweb.asm.Label-int-) to get the index I'm requiring for the second run.

However, having learned that [I can do method call elimination / inlining without having to resort to such a two-pass approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47674972/getting-the-number-of-local-variables-in-a-method), I'm reluctant to do that now.
(I also understand `visitLocalVariable` to be merely debugging information, but since it includes the actual indices, it shouldn't be as problematic as in the question linked to.)

Is there a way that avoids two passes?

Comment: Just curious. What exactly does the rule may give you? Do you know that compiler/JIT may re-arrange local variables if it wishes?

Comment: @kan I don't see why that's an issue. IF JIT can move the variable to another index and actually decides to do that, it will have to update all uses of that local variable, too. Either way, it would be happening after I instrumented the class, at which point I don't care where the local ends up during execution.

Comment: Can you explain what you’re going to do with the variables, once you know it’s index? It seems you want to change it while the code is executing, but that would imply repeated polling code. But what about currently existing copies, e.g. on the operand stack? Further, I would like to know what you mean with “certain methods' arguments cannot be modified without violating java security policies (i.e. crashing)”…

Comment: I don't think you can assume "the dedicated local variable will always hold a reference to it".  The same variable slot can point to a different named variable at different points in a method.  If a compiler were to determine that the `Crucial` instance already exists on the stack, and the storage is no longer needed because the on-stack value can be used, it might start using its slot for another variable.  In the `bar` example, `crucial` may never be saved to a local.  It's unclear what you're trying to do, but I suspect you'll need to do some data flow analysis if you want to get it right.